# Can you help me fix a logic error in my code where it prints a value the amount of times instead of the product

Tags: python, tkinter

My code is meant to get user input, and then multiply by the value chosen in the drop down menu made up of the dictionary options. However, instead it prints the conversion rate the amount of times that the user enters.

```
from tkinter import * #Imports everything from the tkinter module
#Imports everything from the math module
wall = Tk() #Creates the window
wall.title('CC V2.1.1.2') #Labels the window with the version number
var = StringVar(wall)
global ConR
ConR = 0
options = {
    'AU': '1',
    'US': '.77',
    'EU': '.55',
    'Yen': '.011',
    'NZ': '1.25',
}
option = OptionMenu(wall, var, *options)#Conversion Rate, default is one (the value that you entered)
var.set('AU')
option.pack()

def evaluate(event):
    ConR = options[var.get()]
    print (ConR)
    res.configure(text = "Converted value: $" + (str(eval(entry.get()*ConR))))#Takes the value entered from entry.bind and multiplies it by the currency chosen by the user, and prints it at the bottom of the window
entry = Entry(wall) #Creates the entry widgit
entry.bind("<Return>", evaluate)
entry.pack()
res = Label(wall)
res.pack()
y = Button(text='Quit', command=quit)#An exit button
y.pack()
wall.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Few issues that I can see -

1. First you are defining the conversion rates as strings, in you dictionary options , it is giving an error for me. You should instead store floats as values.
2. Secondly, even the result of `entry.get()` is a string , you should convert to float.
3. You should not use `eval()` , after converting the result of `entry.get()` to float and using `float` for the options, you can directly multiply them and show the result.

Code -

```
from tkinter import * #Imports everything from the tkinter module
#Imports everything from the math module
wall = Tk() #Creates the window
wall.title('CC V2.1.1.2') #Labels the window with the version number
var = StringVar(wall)
global ConR
ConR = 0
options = {
    'AU': 1,
    'US': .77,
    'EU': .55,
    'Yen': .011,
    'NZ': 1.25,
}
option = OptionMenu(wall, var, *options)#Conversion Rate, default is one (the value that you entered)
var.set('AU')
option.pack()

def evaluate(event):
    ConR = options[var.get()]
    print(repr(ConR))
    try:
        result = float(entry.get()) * ConR
        res.configure(text = "Converted value: $" + str(result))
        #Takes the value entered from entry.bind and multiplies it by the currency chosen by the user, and prints 
    except:
        res.configure(text = "String not allowed !")

it at the bottom of the window
entry = Entry(wall) #Creates the entry widgit
entry.bind("<Return>", evaluate)
entry.pack()
res = Label(wall)
res.pack()
y = Button(text='Quit', command=quit)#An exit button
y.pack()
wall.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! If you have a reddit account, can you link it to me and can I give you gold? You have no idea how much I love you for this.